# SquirrelFish seems to miss "bind()", how to bind a JS callback to "this" without it?

Tags: javascript, samsung-smart-tv

anybody knows who to bind a JS callback to "this" without "bind()"?

[according to Samsung specs:](http://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/specifications/general-features)

2013 is on V8 : works fine (see [linked shot](http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/b617332e-bbb2-40e7-80d2-ac86f8718713-original.jpeg), too large to add)

2012 is on SquirrelFish : gets exception: "bind()" is not available as a function (see [linked shot](http://image-store.slidesharecdn.com/511454e5-1920-42fe-9b8c-1802b5b4738f-original.jpeg), too large to add)

the offending code is this:

```js
  var extJsCallBacks = [
          function(){this._setupSystemInfo();}.bind(this), 
          function(){this._setupConfigInfo();}.bind(this),
          function(){this._setupRepository();}.bind(this), 
          function(){this._setupContents();}.bind(this)
          ];
```

any hints?

Comment: There is a polyfill in the [documentation of `Function#bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) on the MDN.

Comment: thx Tomalak, it works perfectly on both TVs now.

Comment: The other common method is simply using a closure variable. `var self = this; var extJsCallBacks = [function(){self._setupSystemInfo();}, ...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) found on MDN

```js
if (!Function.prototype.bind) {
  Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {
    if (typeof this !== 'function') {
      // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5
      // internal IsCallable function
      throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');
    }

    var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        fToBind = this,
        fNOP    = function() {},
        fBound  = function() {
          return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP
                 ? this
                 : oThis,
                 aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
        };

    if (this.prototype) {
      // Function.prototype doesn't have a prototype property
      fNOP.prototype = this.prototype; 
    }
    fBound.prototype = new fNOP();

    return fBound;
  };
}
```